# Uploading large CSV-file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I'm trying to upload a CSV-file with coordinates of about 80,000 lines, when ever I uploading the file to QGIS, for some reason, the coordinates don't display right and spreading equally. But when I upload one by one (for testing) the position is correct.

[image]

[image]

It does not matter from me the map I just want use intersection with polygons and points in order to get values ​​for points.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data? It's hard to know why anything might be happening when we can't see the data, even a screenshot of the first few rows would help. Can you also tell us what version of QGIS you are using.

Comment: its is working when i upload one but not all,

Comment: cant upload a photo, but this is the coordinates  for one of them 32.14 34.79

Comment: It would be important to see how the data is structured exactly - just coordinates does not help so much. Just press the screenshot button on your keyboard and paste (CTRL-V) in the text field where you insert your question here on StackExchange.

Comment: Or upload the file someplace like Google Drive or the like and put the link here.Make sure you set the file to public sharing

Comment: THE LINK https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sgUiaEexzkIAQDptHgtIROyzo6-hFgD8?usp=sharing

Comment: How exactly do you "upload" it! Please share a screenshot of the dialog.

Comment: Could you show an unformatted example of your data, e.g open the csv with wordpad instead of excel?

Answer (score 2):

The grid you see when you add your CSV to QGIS is caused by the precision of your coordinates. They only have two (sometimes only one or none at all) decimals. See this OSM wiki for an explanation of precision of coordinates: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Precision_of_coordinates

So from QGIS side, everything looks just fine. The error is caused earlier, maybe within Excel or wherever your data comes from. E.g. some MS Office products like access use the Windows OS settings for decimals which is two by default.

As a conclusion you need to fix your data acquisition.

Comment: so why its working fine  when I upload a small sample

Comment: Please show a  good import. Which column of your csv contains the right coordinates? e.g. I see a coordinate pair in column E which has rounded values in columns F and G.